# Top menu bar disappeared in redhat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally hid my Gnome Panel](https://superuser.com/questions/102143/i-accidentally-hid-my-gnome-panel)

My Redhat EL4 lost its menu bar on top. It just disappeared when I logged in one day. I tried to restart it several times but still is not coming back.

Is there any setting or configuration to get it back?

I am just using the machine with right click->open terminal option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are we talking about GNOME? If yes, please have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/102143/help-i-accidentally-hid-my-gnome-panel).

Comment: This would be better as a comment.